# Especificar apenas um campo obrigatório de um objeto

Tags: typescript

Queria saber se é possível especificar apenas um campo obrigatório para um objeto com typescript. Um exemplo para explicar a dúvida:

```
interface Data {
    id: string | number,    
}

function log (data: Data) {
    console.log(data)
}

log({id: 1, name: 'foo'})
```

Neste exemplo eu queria que o objeto passado para a função `log` tenha o campo `id` obrigatoriamente, mas pudesse ter qualquer outro campo nesse objeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar uma funcionalidade chamada **`dynamic properties`** que consiste na criação de propriedades dinamicas a partir de um modelo:

```
interface Data {
  id: string | number,
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean    
}

function log (data: Data) {
  console.log(data)
}

log({id: 1, name: 'arroz'})
log({id: 1})
log({id: 1, name: 10, test: true})
```

> Pode ver o exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWWABMAuZAZzClAHNkAfZEAVwFsAjaAGgKIDaAawgBPCtVog6AXQk16TFh25QlnAPYaANhDggiRAgF8CBGKxAIwwDQe0aGAChIY4FdJgCUOfsgR2lDoQAHQOdC5uXiZm%20OFO2KQUAIw8LHDsEBQA5HBQUBoAXtnG0XGOCUnIyaUE8Ynk1WkgGVnVAAxpkNQUNKwQpUA).

Comment: Muito obrigado!